# Delete Duplicate Members of N-Dimensional Vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

Recursive templates are still quite confusing to me, and I don't feel like I'm using them as well as I should be.  For example, I tried to use recursive templates to write a function that will remove all duplicate members of an n-dimensional vector, and I believe that I have some code that works.  However, I'm almost confident that there's a better way to do this:

```
  template <typename T>
  void remove_if_duplicate(std::vector<T>& vec, bool at_end)
  {
    static std::set<T> seen;
    if(!at_end)
    {
      auto newEnd = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [=](const T& value)
      {
        if(seen.find(value) != std::end(seen))
          return true;

        seen.insert(value);
        return false;
      });
      vec.erase(newEnd, vec.end());
      std::cout << "\n\nhere: " << at_end << "\n\n";
    }
    if(at_end) {seen.clear();}
  }

  template <typename T>
  void remove_if_duplicate(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v, bool at_end)
  {
    if(!at_end)
    {
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      {
        remove_if_duplicate(v[i], at_end);
      }
    }
    if(at_end) {remove_if_duplicate(v[0], at_end);}
  }

template <typename T>
void remove_duplicates(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
{
  remove_if_duplicate(v, false);
  remove_if_duplicate(v, true);
}
```

See an example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e11f9ababcdfa12

Notice how I declare the set variable "seen" as a static variable of the base function.  I have do this so that I still have access to previous items that I have "seen" before even when iterating through multidimensional vectors.  I cannot declare the "seen" variable inside the second function because the base type that the multidimensional vectors is templated on is unknown at that point (and then the case of a single-dimensional vector wouldn't work either).  So then I have to pass booleans into these functions in order to decide when to actually clear the static set variable so that I can use this function again for other n-dimensional vectors.

While it seems to work so far and is giving me the behavior I want, I'm not sure if any unexpected bugs will appear as a result of my poor implementation.  I think that the way that I have done this here is far from ideal, and I'm sure there's a better, more efficient way.  **How would you do it differently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get rid of the static by using an helper class to construct the correct `set`:

```
template <typename T> struct inner_type
{
    using type = T;  
};

template <typename T> struct inner_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = typename inner_type<T>::type;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
template <typename T>
void RemoveDuplicatesImpl(std::vector<T>& v,
                          std::set<T>& values)
{
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const T& t)
        {
            return !values.insert(t).second;
        }), v.end());   
}

template <typename T>
void RemoveDuplicatesImpl(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v,
                          std::set<typename inner_type<T>::type>& values)
{
    for (auto& inner : v) {
        RemoveDuplicatesImpl(inner, values);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::set<typename inner_type<T>::type> values;
    RemoveDuplicatesImpl(v, values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a set at all.   Since you're using a `std::set`, the order of the elements in the resultant vector doesn't matter.

```
template<class T> void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<T> &v)
{
     std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
     v.erase(v.begin(), std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
}

template<class T> void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<std::vector<T> > &v)
{
      // remove duplicates from every individual vector

      for (auto &i : v)  RemoveDuplicates(e);

      //  for every vector, remove any copy of its elements in subsequent vectors
      auto i = v.begin();
      auto end = v.end();
      while (i != end)
      {
           auto next = std::advance(i, 1);    // alternatively next = i+1
           auto next_i = next;
           while (next != end)
           {
               for (const auto &e : *i)
                   next->erase(next->begin(), std::remove(next->begin(), next->end(), e));
               next = std::advance(next, 1);      // alternatively ++next
           }
           i = next_i;
      }
 }
```